# 'IFormFile' does not contain a definition for 'GetFileName'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to write an action to upload a file and when I try to call GetFileName() method I get this error:

```
'IFormFile' does not contain a definition for 'GetFileName' and no accessible extension method 'GetFileName' accepting a first argument of type 'IFormFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

my controller uses the following namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

and the action is:

```
 [HttpPost]  
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)  
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)  
            return Content("file not selected");  
            var path = Path.Combine(  
                  Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", file.GetFileName());  
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))  
            {  
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);  
            }  
            return RedirectToAction("Files");  
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the filename of the uploaded file using IFormFile we can get it using file.FileName.

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]  
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)  
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length == 0)  
            return Content("file not selected");  
            var path = Path.Combine(  
                  Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", file.FileName);  
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))  
            {  
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);  
            }  
            return RedirectToAction("Files");  
        }
```